# Reading a file located in a jar as java.io.File object

Tags: java

Similar questions to this one were posted, but none of the answers seems to help in my case. 
I am writing a package that uses Google's credentials to obtain Google Apps users. For this, I am using a service account, and so in order to retrieve the credentials, I need to provide (among others) a p12 signature file:

```
   Credential credential = null;
    try {
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File( java.io.File ))
```

The last function must receive a java.io.File object of the p12 signature file. Now, this whole thing runs inside a jar I am providing to others, and that creates most of the problems. I couldn't read the file when running inside the jar no matter which approach I took. Among things I tried:

```
return new File(GoogleUserFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/" +  filePath).toURI());
```

// (I also tried without the "/" and using class.GetResource() directly)

```
URL url = GoogleUserFactory.class.getResource("/" + filePath);
return new File(url.getPath());
```

// I also tried class.GetClassLoader.GetResource()...

Even tried to read the file as a InputStreamReader and write to a new File (which after I will create a File object for and return it), but since I am in a jar, I cannot seem to have permissions to write a new file)

Comment: `java.io.File` works with the file system; things inside another file are not on the file system any more than they would be to _ls_ or _dir_ console commands.

Comment: If you use Java 7 and this API can read from a `Path`, then you can use the zip `FileSystem`

Comment: Google should be ashamed of providing an API that reads from a File instead of reading from an InputStream. Your best bet is to copy the resource to a temporary file, and pass this temporary file to the google API.

Comment: JB Nizet, that's the thing, I cannot seem to create a temporary file because of permission issues.

Comment: fge, The Path class is essentially using a local File system similar to File, and it creates the same problem when running within a jar

Comment: How do you create your temp file? Are you using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29?

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use `.setServiceAccountPrivateKey(SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), SOME_INPUT_STREAM, "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");`, as proposed [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=857) ?

Comment: Yes, eventually that's what I did, and it solved my issue. However, in order to add this functionality to the GoogleCredential#Builder class, I had to modify Google's api-client source code and build it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please try without getClassLoader(). Probably you tried it. but it must work. if you receive NullPointerException filePath can be wrong.

```java
File file = new File(GoogleUserFactory.class.getResource("/" + filePath).toURI());
```