# getClass().getResourcesAsStream() works fine but getClass().getResources() doesn't in exported jar

Tags: java, jar, filepath

I have tried all kinds of getting resources and dealing with files everything works great running in the textEditor(I use Eclipse), But when exported the program into jar, `getResource().getPath()` which I use for creating a file, `FileNotFoundException` occurs, Only stream and url works which can't be used to create a file, I don't understand the problem, please help. Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2343229/3365426

Comment: Thanks @DavidH., But the problem was creating file from the resources inside the jar file, as similar to [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416171/reading-a-file-located-in-a-jar-as-java-io-file-object)